# Have netstat not display port numbers for foreign address

Tags: command-line, netstat

I would like to get netstat to not display port numbers on the foreign address so I can run some statistics on it. This is for a FreeBSD system.

The following is a example of the output.

```
<root>:/# netstat -an | grep .80 |head
tcp4       0      0  61.129.65.176.80      123.120.207.172.51972   ESTABLISHED
tcp4     491      0  61.129.65.176.80      171.250.180.211.51000  ESTABLISHED
tcp4     286      0  61.129.65.176.80      123.120.207.17210399     ESTABLISHED
tcp4     299      0  61.129.65.176.80      211.8.128.46.35458    ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  61.129.65.176.80      123.139.147.112.62778    ESTABLISHED
tcp4     361      0  61.129.65.176.80      239.187.139.47.17607  ESTABLISHED
tcp4     509      0  61.129.65.176.80      74.74.87.36.7822   ESTABLISHED
tcp4     324      0  61.129.65.176.80      75.30.126.198.60721     ESTABLISHED
tcp4     508      0  61.129.65.176.80      149.78.116.66.12120   ESTABLISHED
tcp4     321      0  61.129.65.176.80      48.150.75.171.2617     ESTABLISHED
<root>:/#
```

Comment: You can filter your output using a tool like `sed`, `awk`, or `cut`. Why not post some sample `netstat` raw output, and then an example of what you want to see? That will help others understand more precisely what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `sed` command at the end of your pipe. It does a greeding search until last `.` and delete it and all digits that follow it.

```
... | sed -e 's/^\(.*\)\.[0-9]*/\1/'
```

It yields:

```
tcp4       0      0  61.129.65.176.80      123.120.207.172   ESTABLISHED
tcp4     491      0  61.129.65.176.80      171.250.180.211  ESTABLISHED
tcp4     286      0  61.129.65.176.80      123.120.207.172     ESTABLISHED
tcp4     299      0  61.129.65.176.80      211.8.128.46    ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  61.129.65.176.80      123.139.147.112    ESTABLISHED
tcp4     361      0  61.129.65.176.80      239.187.139.47  ESTABLISHED
tcp4     509      0  61.129.65.176.80      74.74.87.36   ESTABLISHED
tcp4     324      0  61.129.65.176.80      75.30.126.198     ESTABLISHED
tcp4     508      0  61.129.65.176.80      149.78.116.66   ESTABLISHED
tcp4     321      0  61.129.65.176.80      48.150.75.171     ESTABLISHED
```